# Using nested hash and a hash as default value isn't working as expected

Tags: ruby, hash

I want to understand why `a` in the following is an empty hash after `a[:a]` is called, which is not empty:

```
a = Hash.new({a:1}) # => {}
a[:a][:a] += 1      # => 2
a                   # => {}
a[:a]               # => {:a=>2}
```

I know that `{a: 1}` is shared between every inexistent key (`a[:something_inexistent]`). But why isn't it displayed as a key of `a`? If possible, using Ruby's internal would be much appreciated.

Comment: `{a:1}` is the default *value*, so if `a` does not have a key `k`, `a[k]` returns `{a:1}` but it doesn't change the hash. If you want to change the hash, `a[:k] = a[:k]; a #=>  {:k=>{:a=>1}}`. `h` would be a better choice than `a` for a variable whose value is a hash, just like `a` would be better than `h` for an array.

Comment: I saw a post recently, which might help: [Bottomless Ruby Hash](http://firedev.com/posts/2015/bottomless-ruby-hash/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because `a[:a]` is never assigned. When you do `a[:a]`, it is not returning the stored value, but is returning the default value.

Unlike this, when you instead have:

```
a = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = {a: 1}}
```

then, whenever a missing key is called, the block is executed, which assigns the value to the key, and `a` will no longer be an empty hash.

Comment: Why does passing an argument of `{a:1}` to `Hash.new` set the default value to be one, though? That seems kind of weird.

Comment: I think part of his confusion is that `a = Hash.new({a:1})` is not the same as `a = {a: 1}`. I know that got me when I first looked at it.

Comment: Ahh, I think I understand now from looking at [the API](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new). See how they pass in "Go Fish" as the argument, and then call `h["c"]` and get "Go Fish" back out? He set the default value for when the key doesn't exist to be another, inner hash `{a:1}`. When he did the `+= 1` command, he actually was changing what the default value was, now made to be `{a:2}`, but never assigned it to any keys so the main hash is still empty.

Comment: That's exactly what sawa answered. Nice answer I hope others make through as I did :)

Comment: Yes I know, that's why I upvoted it and didn't make my own answer.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the default value is {a:1}, not 1.